# Reversing the effect of killall -u username

Tags: killall

In my action to change my admin username to a new username I used the command:

```
sudo killall -u oldname
```

which logged me out of my admin account, and wiped the processes out. I have been unable to return to my admin account since then.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your computer

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I could only do that through the guest accounts, since i can no longer log into my admin account.

Comment: Then either do that through guest or hard reboot.